# Best UI design to handle no internet connection

Tags: android

My app like many others needs an internet connection constantly. In my main activity I have:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    if (!isOnline()) {
        Intent disconnected = new Intent(this, Disconnected.class);
        startActivity(disconnected);
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

The Disconnected activity displays a TextView with a message and a retry Button.
 Now the problem with this is that if the user presses back he immediately ends up in the Disconnected activity again and isn't able to exit the application using back.
What's an elegant way to handle no internet connection? My main activity is a ListView, should I just have hidden Views that only appear when there's no connection? (I don't feel this is the right way though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be several options

**Option 1:**

Use AlertDialog to show the disconnection. Set it to non cancelable and with two buttons like retry and exit.

**Option 2:**

start disconnection activity using start activity for result if the network disconnection occurs. In the new activity there is a retry button. If retry is set the set OK and finish. And if back button press set CANCEL. now in first activity in onActivityResult if you get RESULT_OK then retry connection.

Comment: I kinda implemented Option 2 and it's working. Since when I press back in the retry screen the application has nothing more to do I want it to close. How can I force the main activity to "back" again (essentially ending the application because it's the root activity) if I detect resultCode CANCEL?

Answer (score 0):

If your starting Activity is just the if statement, and only meant for checking if the user have an internet connection, you could simply finish that Activity when you enter the `Disconnected` Activity

You do this by calling `StartActivity` with the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag set.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    if (!isOnline()) {
        Intent disconnected = new Intent(this, Disconnected.class);
        disconencted.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(disconnected);
    }
    else {
        ...  // Here you would want to do the same thing; 
             // if not, the user could navigate back to this activity as well
    }
}
```

I couldn't test this, but I think it should work.